# Why can't I move whenever I join on external server like Lifeboat and Minedox?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to connect to a Minedox server, and have registered my Minecraft account. However, when I connect, my character just stands there. The graphics appear to error, but live chat runs fine.

[image] [image]

I am running version 0.12.1 on a Lenovo phone. I am connecting from the Philippines. I have already tried playing around the the settings and re-calibrating my touch input. I have also tried restarting my phone, and reinstalling the game.

Why can't I move my character around, when I join external servers, such as Lifeboat and Minedox?

Comment: Try recalibrating your touchscreen or playing around with the options. If that doesn't help (and you already have registered an account to the server) try reinstalling the whole game and restarting your phone.

Comment: Hi,I tried your advice and it still remains the same. This still shows up. Please see the link. My screeenshots of me on external server were there. https://plus.google.com/116192889172604716865/posts/cYTDqVL67i4 do you know where's the problem? :(

Comment: Is it working for other players on the server?

Comment: They live chat on minedox server is running, though. So I believe, it's a yes. :(

Comment: Have you registered on their server? Some servers won't let you move until you're registered. Better yet, have you asked the admins of the server about it?

Answer (score 1):

THE SAME HERE the only fix is

1. GO TO your Pc and install Mhotspot the run it.

Mhotspot will share the wireless or will use the Wifi as Internet Source It Should Work.

My Phone does that too When I join servers it spawns me in the sky

Cause:
Your wifi  has an Outdated Ip or outdated firmware.

That's why we use the Mhotspot. to Get the Correct and The latest Ip

It Really Works for That's why mom says: why do I turn on the Computer.

I answered: I got to turn it on cause it Lets me Join Servers In mcpe...

TO make you Understand

Step 1- Go to your computer then install Mhotspot after installation. Run it

Step 2- Put The Name of your hotspot and put a password and thenTurn on the hotspot...

By the way if you receive an error any error on the Mhotspot just ignore it..
Its kind of a bug.. every error theres an ok button just click the okay then Restart the Mhotspot..

Mine too I Keep having errors in Turning the hotspot on and im just ignoring and after I restart the Mhotspot it starts the Hotspot correctly..

Step 3-Connect Your device on the Hotspot

Its just like When using Hotspot when Joining Mcpe Local Worlds...

Step 4- We are finished join in servers now

Comment: Can you edit your post with less Caps and maybe a better format and spelling? I tried but noticed that I can't understand it all.